# On button click transition for height not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanted to increase the height of div on button click thus decided to use transition. But when I click on button height increases but without transition. Here is my code:

```
.view-all-container{
  max-height: 0;
  overflow-y:hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.7s linear
}

.view-all-container.expanded {
  max-height: 500px;
}



let btn = document.querySelector('.view-all-button');
      let list = document.querySelector('.view-all-container');
      btn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        list.classList.toggle("expanded");

        const expanded = list.classList.contains("expanded");
        if (expanded) {
            btn.innerHTML = "Hide All";
            list.style.overflow = 'scroll'
        list.style.overflowX= 'hidden';
        } else {
            btn.innerHTML = "View All";
            list.classList.remove("expanded");
        }
      })
```

Comment: Post html please

Comment: I don't think you can use the 'transition' property. It is usually used with :hover, :checked, :active etc...

Comment: @ChongLipPhang  why not? You can use transition property

Comment: I  just don't think the 'transition' property reacts to class changes.

Comment: Changing the max-height by itself doesn't really mean anything unless the content is also chaning. A [mcve] is required.

Comment: ok...learned something today. :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what really you are trying to do, but if you run the below code it works as expected, if your intention is to change height on button click

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <button class='view-all-button'>Hit Me</button>
        <div class='view-all-container'></div>
    </body>
    <style>
        .view-all-container {
            max-height: 500;
            overflow-y: hidden;
            height: 200px;
            border: 2px solid #000;
            transition: height 5s linear
        }
    
        .view-all-container.expanded {
            height: 500px;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        let btn = document.querySelector('.view-all-button');
        let list = document.querySelector('.view-all-container');
        btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
            list.classList.toggle("expanded");
            const expanded = list.classList.contains("expanded");
            if (expanded) {
                btn.innerHTML = "Hide All";
                list.style.overflow = 'scroll'
                list.style.overflowX = 'hidden';
            } else {
                btn.innerHTML = "View All";
                list.classList.remove("expanded");
            }
        })
    </script>
    
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works. Run the code snippet below

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('expand-button');
let container = document.getElementById('container');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  container.classList.toggle("expanded");
  const expanded = container.classList.contains("expanded");
  if (expanded) {
    btn.innerHTML = "Contract";
    container.style.overflow = 'scroll';
    container.style.overflowX = 'hidden';
  } else {
    btn.innerHTML = "Expand";
    container.classList.remove("expanded");
  }
})
```

```css
#container {
  max-height: 500;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  transition: height 1s linear;
}

#container.expanded {
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>CSS Transition</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button id='expand-button'>Click Here</button>
  <div id='container'></div>
</body>

</html>
```